# Show that for $P$ a partition of $[a,b]$, $L(g,P)\leq L(f,P)$ if $g(x)\leq f(x)$

Tags: calculus

Suppose functions $f$ and $g$ are continuous and bounded. For $P$ a partion of $[a,b]$, show that $L(g,P)\leq L(f,P)$ if $g(x)\leq f(x)$.

I am completely stuck. I tried using Darboux integrals and got stuck. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have 
$$L(f, P) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(x_{i+1}-x_i)m_{f,i}$$
Where $x_i$ are the endpoints of the partition, and $m_{f,i}$ is the infimum of $f(x)$ on $P_i = [x_i, x_{i+1}]$. Since $g \leq f$, we have 
$$\inf_{x\in P_i} g(x) \leq \inf_{x\in P_i} f(x)$$
In other words, $m_{g,i} \leq m_{f,i}$ for all $i$. Therefore, 
$$L(g, P) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(x_{i+1}-x_i)m_{g,i}\leq \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(x_{i+1}-x_i)m_{f,i}=L(f, P)$$
Since each term in the left sum is less than or equal to the corresponding term on the right side.

(you actually don't need continuity for this result)